# SqlAlchemy memory management

Tags: python, memory-management, memory-leaks, sqlalchemy, memory-consumption

I am trying to optimize memory consumption in one of the scripts and use `memory_profiler` module to track memory consumption.

Here's an example of what it shows:

```py
 91.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           items = Items.query.filter(
106.1 MiB     14.9 MiB           1               Items.instance_id == instance_id,
                                             ).all()
106.1 MiB      0.0 MiB        4116           items_ids = [i.id for i in items]
106.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           zipfile.append(
106.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1               "items.json",
106.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1               json.dumps(
108.4 MiB      2.3 MiB           1                   ItemDumpSchema(many=True).dump(items)
                                                 )
                                             )
106.9 MiB     -1.5 MiB           1           del items
```

As you can see, when getting a list of elements from the database, memory consumption increased by 14.9MiB.

Then I save this data to a zip archive in RAM and the compressed data in it increases the consumption by another 2.3 MiB.

But when I call `del items` after that, the memory is freed by only 1.5 MiB.

I think sqlalchemy still keeps references to these objects as they are bound to the current session, but I don't understand how to clear them.

I tried `session.expunge_all ()` but it didn't work.
Also I tried calling `gc.collect()` and that didn't work either.

---

SQLAlchemy version 1.2.12

Python version 3.6

Comment: Questions about your real world requirement: Do you need to fetch actual objects or is it enough to fetch just the values that you need (in the example you are only using `id`).  Do you need the list of `Items` or can you iterate over the query without calling `.all()`?

Comment: @snakecharmerb, yes, I put a complete dump of objects in the archive

Comment: I've tried iterating over objects via `yield_per ()` but the memory consumption is the same. But I'm more interested in understanding the mechanism itself, why after deleting objects, the memory is not cleared completely